# What's the difference between product of disjoint cycles vs cycles for permutations?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm getting very confused by products of cycles vs disjoint cycles. They look exactly the same to me and the way to compute them seems the same.

Comment: A way to represent a permutation is by its cycle decomposition.

Comment: There is no such thing as product of cycles, there is only composition of permutations.

Comment: Check out http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~lomonaco/f11/653/handouts/Permutations-Handout.pdf
It says "written as a product of cycles", but that to me looks like a disjoint cycle representation.

Comment: I wouldn't get too worried by that. He just means he puts the permutation in disjoint cycle notation.

Comment: He seems to denote composition of permutations as product.

Comment: Okay thank you. What would a disjoint cycle representation be for either of those? Like for the a permutation, wouldn't it be what is listed as the "product of cycles"?

Comment: Yes, it would be exactly the same thing.